# Using Request.Files.Count with TestControllerBuilder from MvcContrib?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mvccontrib

I have a controller action in ASP.NET MVC that handles uploaded files. However, it seems there is no way to call `Request.Files.Count` while using MvcContrib's `TestControllerBuilder`.

I know I can work around this by abstracting `Request.Files`. My questions are:

1. Is it indeed the case that there is no direct way to call `Request.Files.Count` when using the `TestControllerBuilder`? Or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there a way to stub the call to `Request.Files.Count` while using `TestControllerBuilder` using Rhino Mocks?
3. Do you think I should submit a request or patch for handling `Request.Files.Count` to MvcContrib?

### Example code:

I want to make sure that there is at least one file in the `Request.Files` collection so I have the following conditional in my action:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Upload() {
        if (Request.Files == null || Request.Files.Count == 0)
            ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please upload a file");
        // do stuff
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am using the `TestControllerBuilder` from MvcContrib to create the test double for my controller tests. However, the call to `Request.Files.Count` always seems to throw a an exception. For example running the following NUnit test throws a `NotImplementedException` during the call to `controller.Upload()` at the call to `Request.Files.Count`:

```
[Test]
public void Upload_should_return_default_view_given_one_file() {
    MyController controller = new MyController();
    TestControllerBuilder controllerBuilder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    controllerBuilder.InitializeController(controller);
    controllerBuilder.Files["file"] = 
        MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpPostedFileBase>();

    var result = controller.Upload() as ViewResult;

    Assert.That(result.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid, Is.True);
    result.AssertViewRendered().ForView(string.Empty);
}
```

I've also attempted stubbing the call to `Request.Files.Count` to no avail (I'm using Rhino Mocks). None of the below work (even if I change `controller` and/or `controllerBuilder` to a stub):

```
controllerBuilder.Stub(cb => cb.HttpContext.Request.Files.Count).Return(1);
controller.Stub(c => c.Request.Files.Count).Return(1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [submitted a patch](http://github.com/mcliment/MvcContrib/commit/dcdcbc93015074be943a1afd59956b54a36023a1) on Github to MvcContrib mantainers, but the changes are very simple to make, the problem is that HttpFileCollectionBase is not implementing Count() and this[int index] methods so they must be overriden by the WriteableHttpFileCollection in MvcContrib.

I paste the code here for completeness, that must be added to WriteableHttpFileCollection class:

```
public override HttpPostedFileBase this[int index]
{
    get { return files[AllKeys[index]]; }
}

public override int Count
{
    get { return files.Count; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach to solve the problem.

SetUp the test:
            string fileName = "Test 1.pdf";
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("log4net.config");
            MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();

```
        builder.Files[fileName] = mock.CreateMock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
        using (mock.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(builder.Files[fileName].FileName)
                  .Return(fileName);
            Expect.Call(builder.Files[fileName].ContentType)
                  .Return(contentType);
            Expect.Call(builder.Files[fileName].ContentLength)
                  .Return(Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length.ToString()));
            Expect.Call(builder.Files[fileName].InputStream)
                  .Return(stream);
        }
```

using the mock:

```
        foreach(string key in Request.Files.AllKeys)
        {
            int lenght = Request.Files[key].ContentLength;
            if (lenght > 0)
            {
                Document document = new Document();
                string fileName = Request.Files[key].FileName;
                byte[] content= new byte[Convert.ToInt32(lenght)];
                Request.Files[key].InputStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
                document.SetContent(content);
                document.MimeType = Request.Files[key].ContentType;
                // do whatever you want...
            }
        }
```